# PIG Data Transformation with Cloudera PIG editor

Tags: apache-pig, transformation, cloudera

I have my data set up in the following structure:

Cited       Citing

```
1000026 4043055
1000033 4190903
1000033 4975983
1000033 4786543
1000043 4091523
1000044 4082383
1000044 4055371
1000045 4290571
1000046 5918892
1000046 5525001
```

I need to create PIG code to transform the data into the following structure:

Cited   Citing

```
1000026 4043055
1000033 4190903, 4975983, 4786543
1000043 4091523
1000044 4082383, 4055371
1000045 4290571
1000046 5918892, 5525001
```

There are 16 million lines of data, so I cannot do it by hand.

I'm using the Cloudera PIG editor. All data is numeric.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use [`GROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#group).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your input is actually `tab delimited or space delimited`. Based on the above input i assumed its `space` delimited.

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\s+')) AS (col1,col2);
C = GROUP B BY col1;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group,FLATTEN(REPLACE(BagToString(B.$1.col2),'_',','));
STORE D INTO 'output';
```

**Output:**

```
1000026 4043055
1000033 4190903,4975983,4786543
1000043 4091523
1000044 4082383,4055371
1000045 4290571
1000046 5918892,5525001
```

The above output will be generated in `output/part*` file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  However my data is in a comma separated text file.  When I run the script that you provided, it produces a Cited and Citing and a NULL field.  How do I change the script to account for a comma delimited file?  Thanks.

Comment: You can combine `A` and `B` into: `A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray);`.  It is much shorter this way.

Comment: @mr2ert, yes you are right, but  instead of single space,  multi space exist in the input then it will not work, that's the reason i didn't combine into single stmt. (used '\\s+' in the second stmt).

Comment: @James,  your input is something like this 1000026,4043055  ?. can you update your original input?